# How to Check if a website contains Flash

Tags: c++, html, flash, visual-c++, mfc

I've created a web browser using mfc and i'm using IHhmlReader to read the contents of html when the user enters a url in the browser and page is completely loaded.Now i want to check if the webpage has any flash  in it.
Any Helps would be highly appreciated.
Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bit difficult to do, just reading from the HTML source, unless you try to instantiate the page and see if it's making a call to the Flash object. I have listed some options you can try, but you'll need to make sure that the code element is not commented out and check include files and iframes to see if Flash is called from there.
* Look for the OBJECT and EMBED tags (see http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html)
* In page's JavaScript, look for SWFObject() call
* Look for the call to .swf file (could even be in an img tag)

Good luck...